# Sharply-peaked and broad functions

Tags: functions, integration

If $f(x)$ is a "very sharply peaked function" why is $$\int\nolimits_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{ikpx}f(x)\;dx,$$ where $k$ is a constant , a "very broad function of $p$"? Is there a way to visualize this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on this, based on the scaling properties of the Fourier Transform.

Note that as $\epsilon\to0$, the graph of $f(\epsilon x)$ stretches out along the $x$-axis, thus becomes more "broad".  At the same time, the graph of $f(x/\epsilon)/\epsilon$ squeezes in along the $x$-axis and stretches out along the $y$-axis, thus becoming more "sharply peaked"

Fix $k$ and let
$$
F(p)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikpx}f(x)\;\mathrm{d}x
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
F(\epsilon p)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ik\epsilon px}f(x)\;\mathrm{d}x\\
             &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikpx}f(x/\epsilon)/\epsilon\;\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$
Thus, as $\epsilon\to0$, $f(x/\epsilon)/\epsilon$ becomes more "sharply peaked" and $F(\epsilon p)$ becomes more "broad" .